# How can I tell if a remnant of granite matches my counter?

Tags: kitchen-counters, granite

I have a kitchen island with a granite countertop which, for various reasons, I would like to make larger. I found a granite company which has a remnant of granite that would match the size I'd like.

The problem is, how do I tell whether it will match my other countertops? My counters are a pretty common granite 'pattern' (brown, black, and white splotches; very similar to [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Stonemark-3-in-x-3-in-Granite-Countertop-Sample-in-Baltic-Brown-DT-G704/203508028)), and they all match perfectly. The piece they have *looks* very similar, but it's very hard to tell. I went to look at it with pictures of my counters, and looked at my counters with pictures of the remnant. But pictures are really bad at showing color, and I just can't tell.

I don't know if this is a question for diy, but can anyone figure out some way I can tell if it'll match? I assume they won't cut me a sample because that's a big job to do just for the possibility of maybe selling a remnant, plus that'll make the remnant smaller - in case I decide not to buy it, it might be harder to sell to someone else.

Comment: it is not possible for them to match unless they were cut from the same block of stone

Answer (score 2):

Whether the photos are good, perfect or rubbish, if the pieces are not from the same stone then they will not match.

They **might** be ok if they are not close together ie they are separated on different worktops.

Answer (score 1):

take pictures of both and compare.

take the photos in the dark and use the flash so that both pictures have the same lighting.

use a tripod so both pictures have the same distance and angle.

Comment: i was going to suggest a flash for consistent lighting too; great minds...